# restore elasticsearch snapshot from a different s3 region

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-elasticsearch

I have an AWS ElasticSearch domain in `eu-west-1` region and have taken a `snapshot` to an S3 bucket sub folder also in the same region.

I have also deployed a second AWS ElasticSearch domain in another aws region - `eu-west-2`.

Added an S3 bucket replication between the buckets but when I try to register the repository on the `eu-west-2` AWS ES domain, I get the following error:

```
500
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"blob_store_exception","reason":"Failed to check if blob [master.dat] exists"}],"type":"blob_store_exception","reason":"Failed to check if blob [master.dat] exists","caused_by":{"type":"amazon_s3_exception","reason":"Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 14F0571DFF522922; S3 Extended Request ID: U1OnlKPOkfCNFzoV9HC5WBHJ+kfhAZDMOG0j0DzY5+jwaRFJvHkyzBacilA4FdIqDHDYWPCrywU=)"}},"status":500}
```

this is the code i am using to register the repository on the new cluster (taken from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-restore):

```
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

host = 'https://search-**es-elk-prod**.eu-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/' # include https:// and trailing /
region = 'eu-west-2' # e.g. us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

# Register repository

path = '_snapshot/es-elk-prod' # the Elasticsearch API endpoint
url = host + path

payload = {
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "es-prod-eu-west-2",
    "region": "eu-west-2",
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/EsProd-***-snapshotS3role-***"
  }
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

from the logs, i get:

```
curl -X GET  'https://search-**es-elk-prod**.eu-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_snapshot/es-mw-elk-prod/_all?pretty'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "amazon_s3_exception",
        "reason" : "Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 72A59132E2830D81; S3 Extended Request ID: o0XalToNp19HDJKSOVxmna71hx3LkwoSFEobm3HQGH1HEzxOrAtYHg+asnKxJ03iGSDDhUz5GUI=)"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "amazon_s3_exception",
    "reason" : "Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 72A59132E2830D81; S3 Extended Request ID: o0XalToNp19HDJKSOVxmna71hx3LkwoSFEobm3HQGH1HEzxOrAtYHg+asnKxJ03iGSDDhUz5GUI=)"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

the `ARN` is able to access the S3 bucket as is the same `ARN` i use to snapshot the `eu-west-2` domain to S3 as the `eu-west-1` snapshot is stored in a sub-folder on the S3 bucket, I added a path to the code, such that:

```
payload = {
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "es-prod-eu-west-2",
    "path": "es-elk-prod",
    "region": "eu-west-2",
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/EsProd-***-snapshotS3role-***"
  }
}
```

but this didn't work either.

What is the correct way to restore snapshot created in one aws region into another aws region?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar but not identical error messages about `The bucket is in this region: eu-west-1. Please use this region to retry the request` when moving from eu-west-1 to us-west-2.

According to [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html) (under "Migrating data to a different domain") you will need to specify an endpoint rather than a region:

> If you encounter this error, try replacing "region": "us-east-2" with "endpoint": "s3.amazonaws.com" in the PUT statement and retry the request.